# How do you compare elements in two hashes

Tags: ruby

I wish to compare two hashes to determine which values can be matched up. For example:

```
hash1 = {
    "hash1_key_a" => 1,
    "hash1_key_b" => 2
}

hash2 = {
    "hash2_key_a" => 1,
    "hash2_key_b" => 3,
    "hash2_key_c" => 4
}

# The method here should display the matching keys & values,
# and then delete them from their hashes. For example:

puts "#{hash1_key_a};#{hash2_key_a};1" # 1 is representing the referral we should
                                       # put in for the value
```

Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You can do a naive double loop.

Comment: You just do it. Use `each_with_index` and the comparison operator, `==`. There is no magic method for doing this for you.

Comment: @meagar: Yet there might be one. Ruby surprises me every single day :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's a pretty specific case for some built-in method to tackle. I'd wager heavily that there isn't one.

Comment: Maybe [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) can do the trick for you?

Comment: `puts "#{hash1.invert()[1]};#{hash2.invert()[1]};1` ?

Comment: If you just want to see which values overlap: `hash1.values & hash2.values`

Comment: wait, what do you mean by "matching keys and values"?  Your two hashes don't have any keys in common, and they're all literal strings, but then you treat them as variables in the `puts` line.  Are you looking for cases where the same *key*,*value* pair is present in both hashes?  Or just the same key, with possibly different values?  Or just the same value, with possibly different keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the hashes have distinct keys? Then you can do something like this:

```
hash1.merge(hash2).group_by{|k,v| v}.each{ |v,ks|
   puts "#{ ks.map(&:first)*';' };#{ v }"
}
```

Comment: J-_-L, that is just genius. Thanks.